# How to fetch Angular JSON value

Tags: json, angularjs

Return json form the API which is

```
    { ACC: "{"NO":"AC307","NAME":"joe"}, RETURN: "TRUE" }
```

i need the value separate as NO, NAME , ... how can i

HTML:

```
  <div ng-repeat="acdetails in accdetails ">
        <div class="item item-divider item-input-wrapper">
           Acc No - {{ acetails.NO }}
        </div>
         <div class="item item-divider item-input-wrapper">
            Name&nbsp; - {{ acdetails.NAME }}
        </div>
   </div>
```

but its displaying as empty ,
i am new to angular help me out

Thank you in advance

Comment: show us how you populate ```acedetails```. Plus, look out for spelling, you have acedetails and acdetails in the HTML

Comment: ya i have updated its a mistake then also it remain same  values are empty

Comment: There is no array shown in api data. What are you trying to `repeat` over? Show more code. You either haven't shown us your data properly or you have a data structure problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this

Actual RETURN DATA:

```
  { ACC: "{"NO":"AC307","NAME":"joe"}, RETURN: "TRUE" }
```

just in your controller use json parse

```
 .success(function(data) {   
            if(data.RETURN == "TRUE") {                    
                var acdetailsObject = JSON.parse(data.ACC);
                $scope.acdetails = acdetailsObject;                                               
            }
```

your data will be as format below

```
       { NO: "AC00316", NAME: "John Doe" }
```

then in your html you can directly fetch using $scope.acdetails with out using any ng-repeat , as below

```
  <div class="item item-divider item-input-wrapper">
       Acc No - {{ acdetails.NO }}
    </div>
     <div class="item item-divider item-input-wrapper">
        Name&nbsp; - {{ acdetails.NAME }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON is invalid. Assuming that in your angular controller you have the following (note that this is an array of objects)

```
$scope.accdetails =  [{ 
    "ACC": {
        "NO":"AC307",
        "NAME":"joe",
    },
    "RETURN": "TRUE" 
}];
```

then the following html displays the desired information

```
    <div ng-repeat="acdetails in accdetails">
        <div class="item item-divider item-input-wrapper">
           Acc No - {{ acdetails.ACC.NO }}
        </div>
         <div class="item item-divider item-input-wrapper">
            Name&nbsp; - {{ acdetails.ACC.NAME }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Good approach by hard coding a set of values. Now OP can work on fixing back end to match

Answer (score 0):

try Changing   `Acc No - {{ acetails.NO }}` to      `Acc No - {{ acetails.ACC.NO }}`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how and why it works.

Answer (score 0):

You JSON is not valid. Valid json below

```
{"ACC": {
    "NO": "AC307",
    "NAME": "joe",
    "ST": "",
    "RETURN": "TRUE"
} }
```

Comment: i have some thing like this { ACC: "{"NO":"AC307","NAME":"joe"}, RETURN: "TRUE" } how can i get